# Run a single line command in a separate directory

Tags: windows, command-line, notepad++, shortcuts

How can I be in one directory, and run a command from another?

Basically it needs to be like the "Start In" parameter of a shortcut. In fact, I actually tried using a shortcut as an alternative, but no luck there.

[Why do you need to do this?]
I need to do it because in Notepad++ I'm trying to run the program I'm making from Notepad++'s 'run command' feature. The problem I'm having is the 'start in' directory is not the location of the executable. I need the 'start in' directory to be the location of the executable.

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean.  You can chain commands into a single line, so `cd \windows & dir` would change directories and execute a command in as single line.

Comment: I already tried that too, it doesn't work. It doesn't even try to work.

Comment: However, that is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: or you could just put in the full path to the executable

Comment: I'm already using the full path, how else would I be executing the file? So, no, that is not the solution either.

Comment: @CoreyIles You have a couple of close votes already.  How about you [edit] your question and be more specific about what you want to do and why it "doesn't work" - more detail about what happens.

Comment: Use the [nppexec plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/NppExec/). It is much more powerful than the standard "run". See [NppExec Manual](http://www.cin.ufpe.br/~aedv/Notepad++Portable/App/Notepad++_ansi/plugins/doc/NppExec_Manual.txt)

Answer (score 2):

When your Notepad++ is installed in `C:\Program Files\NPP` and you want to execute a program that is located in `C:\Program Files\Prg`, named `abc.exe` you can do this using the following command:

```
..\Prg\abc.exe
```

You can test this by running a cmd.exe prompt, and executing

```
 cd C:\Program Files\NPP
..\Prg\abc.exe
```

Another way of executing the abc.exe is by using the full path:

```
"C:\Program Files\Prg\abc.exe"
```

Note that you need to use "quotes" because the path contains spaces.

Comment: Yes, of course I can execute the program like that. I have no problem executing in the first place though. The problem is that the 'start in' directory is not the location of the executable.

Comment: Then you should create a batch file that first changes to the directory you want to start your program in, followed by starting the executable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `/D path` option of the `start` command. Something like:

`start /D c:\windows cmd` will open a new terminal window in c:\windows directory.